# Load web form inside another web froms div

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Hello how i can load web forms inside one web forms div/

SO i have web form 'account' which opening inside master page.

on my account web form i have menu i want when user clicks it to load another web form inside account page.

I am using ASP.NET C#.

Sorry For My Bad English.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look at opening your second page/form in a iFrame.  This can be triggered via JavaScript when you click a option in your menu.

Comment: there is also the alternative of nesting master pages. You could have accountMaster and the other pages use accountmaster as its master page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this server-side this can be accomplished by loading an instance of a  usercontrol into your form vs. the actual page.  [Click here to see an MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86.aspx) and be sure to use update panels to manage the post backs.

If you want to do this client side you can do so via ajax and calling an ashx (handler file)
To manage this client side:

within your aspx file add the following:

within the header

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#panel").hide();
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".slide").click(function () {
                $("#panel").show("slow", false);

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "controlloader.ashx",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        jQuery('#loadcontrol1').append(response);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        jQuery('#loadcontrol1').append('error');
                    }
                });

            });

        });
</script>
```

And then within the body

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <div id="panel" >
        <p>stuff here</p>
        </div>
        <p><%= DateTime.Now %></p>
        <div id="div1" class="slide">
            <p class="btn-slide">Expand Panel</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button Text="Click me" ID="clickButton" runat="server" />

        <div id="loadcontrol1" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Then within your ashx file

```
public class controlloader : IHttpHandler
    {
        //If annonymous id is turned on IRequireSessionState Interface may be needed to write session variabled such as user auth.
        // Generic handlers by default implementIReadOnlySessionState
        public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write(RenderPartialToString("~/Control1.ascx")); ;
        }

        private string RenderPartialToString(string controlname)
        {
            Page page = new Page();
            Control control = page.LoadControl(controlname);
            page.Controls.Add(control);

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);

            return writer.ToString();
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

You will also need to create the user control file but I'll leave that code to you. 
There are a few things happening in this example. The button is used to proveout post-backs to ensure the control is not reloaded. I also added an animation which you don't need but this was an old proof-of-concept piece I had from a while back so you can ignore that chuck of code.

I know you mentioned the user of master pages so you will more than likely want to factor out the javascript into a js file and then be sure to load it using script manager as:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery-1.7.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/yourcontrolloader.cs" />
</scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

This is required when using master pages otherwise due to the server side rendering your references will be lost and the scripts never called. You could also use a partial reference in the actual page vs the masterpage but this is up to you.

Best of luck